# Problem with a loop when making adjacency matrix

Tags: loops, social-networking, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

Problem with a loop in the adjacency matrix:

I have a dataset (all_connected_names1) of two columns: `Data_Name` and `Name` that contain names of the organizations (`Data_Name`) and corresponding people working in those organizations (`Name`). I'm trying to make an adjacency matrix based on the organizations that have same people working there - nodes are organizations from `Data_Name` column and edges people from `Name` column.

However, when I do the matrix the loop returns empty and graph shows as if there are no connections.

This is the code I'm using:

```
# Get unique organization names from the Data_Name column
organizations <- unique(all_connected_names1$Data_Name)
organizations

# Create an empty adjacency matrix with dimensions based on the number of organizations
adjacency_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = length(organizations), ncol = length(organizations))
rownames(adjacency_matrix) <- as.character(organizations)
colnames(adjacency_matrix) <- as.character(organizations)

# Iterate over the rows of the combined dataset
for (i in 1:(nrow(all_connected_names1) - 1)) {
  current_organization <- trimws(all_connected_names1$Data_Name[i])
  next_organization <- trimws(all_connected_names1$Data_Name[i + 31])
  name <- trimws(all_connected_names1$Name[i + 31])
  
  # Check if the same name appears next to different organizations
  if (is.na(current_organization) != is.na(next_organization)) {
    adjacency_matrix[current_organization, next_organization] <- 1
    adjacency_matrix[next_organization, current_organization] <- 1
  }
  
  # Check if the same name appears next to the same organization
  if (current_organization == next_organization) {
    adjacency_matrix[next_organization, next_organization] <- 1
  }
}
```

I also tried making an adjacency list or an edge list, but with no success